# Be notified when folder contents changes - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

In my program I'd like to be notified when a user inserts a usb/firewire/etc drive in the computer.

I don't know if there is a special way just for drives, but I think there should be a way with normal folders. Since all external drives are in the /Volumes folder, I'd like a way to observe that folder and have a method called or something when it's contents change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [File Systems Events API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  It's C API, not an Objective-C API, but it's still perfectly usable from Objective-C.